# Flot - Plotting Month, Priority & Owner

Tags: javascript, flot

I have a question with regards to plotting data using Flot.

I am looking to Plot a Priority as Series, the Month in which the Priority occured, but also an Owner of that Priority.

I am looking for the Owner to have a stacked column of priorites in the relevant month.

Below is the Fiddle, which I have the Month and priority, but I am very confused when it comes to adding in an Owner.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
    var graphP1 = [
    ["JAN", 5],
    ["FEB", 3],
    ["MAR", 22]
];
var graphP2 = [
    ["JAN", 3],
    ["FEB", 12],
    ["MAR", 9]
];
var graphP3 = [
    ["JAN", 7],
    ["FEB", 18],
    ["MAR", 7]
];
var graphP4 = [
    ["JAN", 9],
    ["FEB", 9],
    ["MAR", 3]
];
var data = [{
    label: "P1",
    data: graphP1,
    bars: {
        show: true,
        fill: true,
        lineWidth: 1,
        order: 1,
        fillColor: "#808080",
        barWidth: 0.5,
        align: "center"
    },
    color: "#808080"
}, {
    label: "P2",
    data: graphP2,
    bars: {
        show: true,
        fill: true,
        lineWidth: 1,
        order: 1,
        fillColor: "#f00",
        barWidth: 0.5,
        align: "center"
    },
    color: "#f00"
}, {
    label: "P3",
    data: graphP3,
    bars: {
        show: true,
        fill: true,
        lineWidth: 1,
        order: 1,
        fillColor: "#ffa500",
        barWidth: 0.5,
        align: "center"
    },
    color: "#ffa500"
}, {
    label: "P4",
    data: graphP4,
    bars: {
        show: true,
        fill: true,
        lineWidth: 1,
        order: 1,
        fillColor: "#e9e96c",
        barWidth: 0.5,
        align: "center"
    },
    color: "#e9e96c"
}];

$.plot($("#thegraph"), data, {
    yaxis: {
        tickFormatter: function (val, axis) {
            return (val);
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: "categories",
        tickLength: 0
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0eaq5w71/)

Answer (score 0):

For stacking bars you need to add the stack plugin and add the option:

```
    series: {
        stack: true
    },
```

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0eaq5w71/1/).